# How can I update the value of an object while mapping through it's array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping through an array and I'm using an input's value to display the objects text like this :

```
        {items.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.text}>
                        <input value={item.text} type="text" />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
```

Now I want to change that specific object text when user clicks on the input so I make an onChange function for the input :

```
<input onChange={(e) => set(e.target.value)} value={item.text} type="text" />
```

And then I get the value in the set function and I want to change the object's text into the new value which user's typing in :

```
    const set = (value) => {
        items.map((item) => {
            if (item.text === value) {
                item.text === value;
            }
            return null;
        });
        console.log(value);
    };
```

But it thows an error :

```
 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Also I guess it wont update that objects value .

So how properly I can update an object's text in the input field while mapping through the whole array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In set method, you are use **comparison** instead of **assignment**

```
  item.text === value;
```

This should update your item object

```
  item.text = value;
```

Comment: Thanks it helped but still item.text = value won't update properly

Comment: @Maxwilliams In the if block return `item`. It's not updating because .map expects a new element to be returned, and you're giving `null`.

Comment: const set = (value) => {
        items = items.map((item) => {
            if (item.text === value) {
                item.text= value;
            }
            return item;
        });
        console.log(value);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Form inputs in React are known as [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and there are some great examples in the docs that should help shed some light on issues like this one. There are also *a ton* of form libraries out there that take a lot of the pain out of managing form state.

Another important detail here is that `array.map` returns a new array, rather than modifying an array in place. So, your `set` function is going to need to `return` a new array with the updates you want, and ideally you’ll be using React’s built in tools (e.g. `useState` or `setState`) to update your list of `items`. Here’s the smallest example I could come up with to try and illustrate that. I’m making some assumptions here that your `items` array is maintained in React state somewhere, and that your `items` array is a simple array of objects with maybe just an `id` and `text` field.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "first", text: "first" },
    { id: 2, name: "second", text: "second" },
    { id: 3, name: "third", text: "third" }
  ]);

  const handleChange = (evt, id) => {
    const { name, value } = evt.target;

    const newItems = items.map(item => {
      if (item.id !== id) {
        return { ...item };
      }

      return { id, name, text: value };
    });

    setItems(newItems);
  };

  const submit = () => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(items));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <form>
        {items.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <input
              name={item.name}
              value={item.text}
              onChange={evt => handleChange(evt, item.id)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export { App as default };
```